# How to show cities according to the state in Form using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I am working on the `Contact Form 7` and I want to show the cities according to state in contact form 7.

I have also used the plugin but it is not working according to the condition and I don't want the country field in that. That's why I am trying my own code.

**I cant ask this question in Contact Form 7 Forum because this is developer need and it requires some JavaScript knowledge.**

**My Code:**

```
[select* your-state first_as_label "Select Your State*" "Andaman and Nicobar Islands" "Andhra Pradesh" "Arunachal Pradesh" "Assam" "Bihar" "Chandigarh" "Chhattisgarh" "Dadra and Nagar Haveli" "Daman and Diu" "Delhi" "Goa" "Gujarat" "Haryana" "Himachal Pradesh" "Jammu and Kashmir" "Jharkhand" "Karnataka" "Kerala" "Ladakh" "Lakshadweep" "Madhya Pradesh" "Maharashtra" "Manipur" "Meghalaya" "Mizoram" "Nagaland" "Odisha" "Puducherry" "Punjab" "Rajasthan" "Sikkim" "Tamil Nadu" "Telangana" "Tripura" "Uttar Pradesh" "Uttarakhand" "West Bengal"]

[select* your-city first_as_label "Select Your City*"]
```

I have the cities list: https://github.com/ajayrandhawa/Indian-States-Cities-Database

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry the Contact Form 7 support forum doesn't provide dev support, but 3rd party dev support is offtopic here

Comment: @TomJNowell, I totally understand that but it is done using Javascript and this is a developer thing. If we are using plugins and there is needed some modification in the plugin then it is a developer thing.

Comment: Generic JS questions belong on stackoverflow, questions on this site must be specific to working with WordPress itself or with 1st party code such as the twenty twenty theme, or feature plugins such as Gutenberg or the 2FA proposal plugin

Comment: @TomJNowell, Okay but we are using WordPress, so I thought that I can ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

**Just Add This Code In Contact Form 7:**

```
<select name="stt" id="sts" class="form-control"  required="" onchange="print_city('state', this.selectedIndex);"></select>
<select name="city" id="state" class="form-control" required=""></select>
<script language="javascript">print_state("sts");</script>
```

And This In `Functions.php`

```
function my_theme_scripts_function() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cities.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_scripts_function');
```

You Can Take The Cities.js File From Here: https://github.com/ajayrandhawa/Indian-States-Cities-Database

**In this, you can add cities you want.**

**For The Mail:**

```
State: [stt]
City: [city]
```

This is the solution.